# how to PostScript True Type 1 mac font embed into flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have the vinyl regular extension of PostScript True Type 1 mac font. How can I embed into my flex application?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [Adobe online write up](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f5f.html) on embedding fonts.

I typically put my font files in my /assets/fonts/ folder, but it's up to you where you put it.

**Example:**

```
@font-face { 
    src: url("assets/fonts/my-font.ttf"); 
    fontFamily: MyFontName;  
    embedAsCFF:true; 
}
```

**Using the font:**

```
<s:Label text="Hello world!" fontFamily="MyFontName" />
```